# What is `delete(<anything>)`?

Tags: javascript, browser, console, keyword, javascript-engine

When I use `delete` keyword as a function it returns `boolean` and if I pass anything it doesn't throw error

```js
const foo = 0
delete(foo) // false

const bar = 1
delete(bar) // false

delete(unknown) // true

delete(5) // true
```

I don't understand this behaviour so I wanna someone to explain to me why javascript works like that

Comment: You're not using it "as a function". You just use the `delete` operator on a parenthesised expression. Notice you get exactly the same results with `delete foo`, `delete bar`, `delete unknown` and `delete 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

The return value is:

> true for all cases except when the property is an own non-configurable
> property, in which case, false is returned in non-strict mode.